# Vite+react app shows blank screen. What to do?

Tags: vite, vite-reactjs

I was following a tutorial of react. I followed all the requirements except I used vite+reactjs instead of reactjs. Now when I run the vite app it shows blank. But I followed everything accordingly.

Here is the github link [REPOLINK](https://github.com/An1MuS1111/Exercise-Tracker.git)

Please help me fix it

Recheaked a lot. But couldn't figure out.

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you manage to find the problem?